# How can i make 1 method act differently based on button clicked?

Tags: android

[image: pic of code]

I have a method which on button click needs to perform in a specific way and if no button is clicked, it should alternatively act differently.

Basically on clicking on the button, it should destroy my service. And if I don't click on it, it will eventually be destroyed. The thing is that I want the destroy method act differently based on these 2 scenarios.

Comment: add the code and some detail for proper understanding.

Comment: @NishantBhakta i've added a pic of my codes. Can you help me now?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You could add the clicked View as method argument:

```
myOnClick(View view){
   if(view != null){
       //Button was clicked
       ....
   }else{
       //No Button was clicked
       .....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the method performing periodically? Then just add a bool to see if the button was clicked before.

like:

Main:

```
boolean clicked = false;
```

onCreate:

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonName);
b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(clicked){
            clicked = false;
        }else{
            clicked = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it is not exactly what  i need; i've edited my question and added more details. can you please propose an alternative solution now?

Comment: i dont understand what you want to do ^^ you should add more details and specify your question